# Why is Dataproc using this weird shaded version of the JSON package and how do I work with it?

Tags: scala, google-bigquery, sbt, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to catch an expected exception from the BigQuery connector. The class of the exception is: `com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException` and I have successfully caught this exception before when it was thrown by the Cloud Storage connector.

When I run the code in Dataproc (Spark), the exception thrown is a similar, but shaded version of this exception: `com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException`.

My code looks like this:

```scala
...
  case e: GoogleJsonResponseException =>
    e.getDetails.getCode match {
      case 404 =>
        ss.emptyDataFrame
      case _ =>
        throw e
    }
  case e: Exception =>
    println(e.getClass) // reaches here
    throw e
...
```

In my `build.sbt` (which I think might be at fault) I have this:

```scala
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule
    .rename("com.google.common.**" -> "repackaged.com.google.common.@1")
    .inAll
)
```

I need this repackaged version to get rid of some of Google's nasty incompatibilities (shame Google, *shame*).

Why does it do shading on this as well though? How can I make it work or work around it?

**Small warning**
I haven't worked a lot with Java and even less with Scala, so I know very little about shading/repackaging - be gentle

---

Edit: As per the comment below, I should probably say more about the exact method.

I am reading data from BQ with `sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD`. The top of the stack trace looks like this:

```
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:401)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1097)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:499)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:432)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.bigquery.com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryHelper.getTable(BigQueryHelper.java:327)
```

Comment: What BQ connector method are you calling that throws this exception?

Comment: I'm trying to read data through `sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD`

Comment: Good question, I think this indicates a design problem with the GCS connector, I filed an [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/issues/239) for the connector.

Comment: Why GCS connector, exception is thrown by BQ connector, no?

Comment: Thanks for report, this shading issue in Hadoop BigQuery connector will be [fixed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/pull/240) in the upcoming 1.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently because of a bug in the BQ connector. Thanks to Dagang and Igor Dvorzhak it will now, allegedly, be fixed in the upcoming 1.0.0 version of the connector (see comment on question).

If you have this issue then wait for the new version to be released. Or if it has been already then update to >1.0.0.

Hope this helps.